# Passing Javascript Variable to second html page and show

Tags: javascript, html

I have two html pages On page one I have stored the value of clicked anchor tag into a variable. Now I just want to send this variable value to page2.html and show it there. My code is as under:

```
<body>
<a href="page2.html" class="#images\shahbaz.jpg" onClick= "myFunction(this.className);"> Hello </a> <br /> <br />

<script>
function myFunction (className){
var abc = className;
document.write(abc);
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: it can't be done with regular javascript and HTML

Comment: You will either need to store it in a client session storage or cookie in JavaScript, or send it via the server using a server sided language.

Comment: or in the url's query string.

Comment: url's querry string?

Comment: @Jahangir As in you could embed your variable into the URL when moving from page1 to page 2, but there are better ways to do it. In regards to the duplicate, you are better off just using `sessionStorage` since you won't need the variable after you close your web browser.